# S/4HANA Cloud SDK: Create sales order with reference to a sales contract

Tags: s4sdk

I would like to create a sales order with reference to a sales contract using the S/4HANA Cloud SDK.  I do not see a get/set method for ReferenceSDDocument at the header- or item-level in the   com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.salesorder.SalesOrder class, even though it is shown in the sample JSON-body in the POST of [/A_SalesOrder in the API Hub](https://api.sap.com/api/API_SALES_ORDER_SRV/resource).  Not sure if I should be somehow using the SalesOrderField class, or something else ... or should be switching to the SOAP API.

Comment: Which version of the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK are you using? Are you using the latest one (2.13.2 at the time of this writing): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cloud.s4hana/sdk-bom/2.13.2

Comment: Looking at 'External Libraries' in IntelliJ, it appears to be 1.11.1.  I used the following to create the project:mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-neo-javaee6 -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST

Comment: Here is a snippet from pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>scp-neo</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana</groupId>
            <artifactId>s4hana-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using version 1.11.1 of the S/4HANA Cloud SDK you have the OData VDM that corresponds to the state of S/4HANA at this point in time.

You now have two options:

1. Use the newer `scp-neo-javaee7` archetype. This exists in version 2.13.2 and supports the latest S/4HANA version.
2. Create your own OData VDM for your system, check [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/) for more information on how to do this.